# Nest.JS Kafka microservice and still listen to port 3000

Tags: typescript, apache-kafka, nestjs

I have a Nest.JS microservice, which starts like this

```
const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, {
  transport: Transport.KAFKA,
  options: {
    client: {
      brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
    }
  }
});
await app.listen()
```

I'm running this microservice on Kuberenets, and I need it to listen to port 3000 (or another port, doesn't really matter) for its liveness and readiness probes. The problem is that when I use

```
NestFactory.createMicroservice()
```

The app.listen() doesn't accept port number, and I can't set the port in the options because the transport Transport.Kafka doesn't accept it either.

What is the best way to approach it? Can I make it listen to port 3000 and still subscribe to a Kafka Topic?

Answer (score 0):

According to NestJ documentation, what you want to do is call Hybrid App. A hybrid application is one that listens for requests from two or more different sources.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

const microservice = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({

  transport: Transport.KAFKA,
  options: {
    client: {
     brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
  }, 
  consumer: {
    groupId: 'some-consumer',
  },
 },
});


await app.startAllMicroservices();
await app.listen(3001);
```

You can read more about it here https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application